# Problem framer motion component in NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, sanity

I am using NEXTJS and SanityIO. I am getting this error when adding this Framer motion component? "TypeError: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component%22)  or it just fails to refresh.

My code causing the problem is below and below the code is a picture of my folder layout. If it is helpful to know, the Header component  works if I just render an h1 alone. Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { SocialIcon } from 'react-social-icons';
    import {motion} from "framer-motion";

     type Props = {}

        function Header({}: Props) {
      return (
        <header className="sticky top-0 p-5 flex items-start justify-between max-w-7xl mx-auto z- 
    20 xl:items-center">
            <motion.div 
             initial={{
               x:-500,
              opacity:0,
            scale:0.5
           }}
            animate={{
            x:0,
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 1
         }}
         transition={{
            duration:1.5,
         }}
         className="flex flex-row items-center">
            {/*Social Icons*/}
            <SocialIcon
                url="https://www.youtube.com"
                fgColor="gray"
                bgColor="transparent"
            />
                 <SocialIcon
                url="https://www.youtube.com"
                fgColor="gray"
                bgColor="transparent"
            />
                 <SocialIcon
                url="https://www.youtube.com"
                fgColor="gray"
                bgColor="transparent"
            />
        </motion.div>

        <motion.div
         initial={{
            x: 500,
            opacity: 0,
            scale: 0.5,
         }}
         animate={{
            x:0,
            opacity:1,
            scale:1,
         }}
         transition={{duration:1.5}}
        
        
            className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer">
           <SocialIcon
                className="cursor-pointer"
                network="email"
                fgColor="gray"
                bgColor="transparent"
            />

            <p className="uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400"> Get In Touch</p>

           </motion.div>
      </header>
     )
    }

    export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problems when using Framer Motion. I think this problem is becoming from the new AppDir of Next.js 13. I read the beta documents here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components

For fixing this issues, I added `'use client';` in the first line before import libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As Phong and the error msg are saying, just adding the "use client" directive at the very top of the file will fix the issue.

By default, Next13 (React18) is introducing a server-side component, which means the component is rendered on the server and shipped to the client

and

the general rule of thumb is that if you are using third-party libraries or you are using hooks, or some interactivity ( e.g. onClick ) - you need to set this "use client" directive.

Basically, if it's possible to make a server component, I'd consider doing it over the client side because less code will be shipped to the client.